Which method do I use to add a .png attachment to an email
I have saved a form screenshot to FileSystemStorage using the following code (1).
When I System.out.println() the path, it is returned as:
file://home/12-16-2024_Game_Plan.png
I then set up the email message to myself, which opens the default email client with the correct subject and message body, using the following code(2).
I have used both the m.setAttachment and m.getAttachments code to attach the .png, but neither adds the .png attachment. I saw a post from 2016 that mentioned a change in the next library build, but I cannot find any other posts that talk about this. Does anyone have any ideas? macOS, M1 MacBook Pro, Mail email client. Thanks.
//1
    public Image getScreenshot() {
        Form form = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if (form != null) {
            fileName = new String(formattedDate + "_Game_Plan.png");
            Image screenshot = Image.createImage(form.getWidth(), form.getHeight());
            form.paintComponent(screenshot.getGraphics(), true);
            imageFile = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getAppHomePath() + fileName;
            try(
                OutputStream os = FileSystemStorage.getInstance().openOutputStream(imageFile)) {
                ImageIO.getImageIO().save(screenshot, os, ImageIO.FORMAT_PNG, 1);
                System.out.println(os);
            } catch(IOException err) {
                Log.e(err);
            }
            form.show();
            return screenshot;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
//2
    public boolean share() {
        sb.setImageToShare(imageFile, "image/png");
        Message m = new Message("Game Plan");
        System.out.println(imageFile);
//        m.setAttachment(imageFile);
//        m.setAttachmentMimeType(Message.MIME_IMAGE_PNG);
        m.getAttachments().put(imageFile, "image/png");
        Display.getInstance().sendMessage(new String[] {"myEmail"}, fileName, m);//jacobs.curtis.l@gmail.com

        new Saved();

        return true;
    }
~~~


This will work on a mobile device but not in the desktop. On mobile we have more sophisticated mail APIs for attachments etc. and in desktop we have some limits.

Understood. My 1st priority is getting the screenshot to the desktop, and neither the set or get-put code attached the screenshot to the created email. I will work on code for the desktop to send the screenshot straight to the printer.

To the desktop or from the desktop version? In the desktop version you can simply save the file in the FileSystemStorage directly into the users Desktop directory.

From the mobile version to email on the desktop. Getting the code to work on the device (in the simulator) opens other uses in the app for the routine. Neither way attached the png to the email.

The simulator doesn't simulate attachments. Is the PNG not attacked to the email you generated on the device?
When you connect a cable to the device and look at its log output do you see any suspect printouts?

Thanks, Shai. I am testing the last 2 modules so I can build for the devices, and test everything on the different platforms. If the simulator does not perform the attachment, I will build and test. Thanks for all your help.
